# How can I use 2 monitors plus laptop with my Dell e6420 w/ Nvidia nvs 4200m

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors, dell-latitude

I have just hooked up a 2nd external monitor to my Dell e6420 laptop with a Nvidia NVS 4200m graphics card, running Windows 8 64 bit.  However, the computer won't let me have both monitors and the laptop display active at the same time.

I installed the latest Nvidia graphics drivers (310.70) but it claims that my GPU can only support up to 2 monitors.  [Nivdia's website](http://www.nvidia.com/object/notebook-nvs.html) implies differently (as does various other laptops around the office).

The monitors are connected both via DVI to my dell docking station that has multiple DVI ports.  Both monitors are working correctly, I just can't get all 3 working together.

Attempting to download the driver from dell fails, as their driver installer is broken apparently

Any ideas?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Windows 8 64 bit

Answer (score 4):

Figured it out.

In BIOS I needed to enable Nvidia Optimus support, and once I rebooted everything works good